# Can't bind gnome-do to Super + Space or Ctrl+Alt+Space

Tags: shortcut-keys, 12.04, gnome-do

With today's updates to 12.04 I can no longer bind **gnome-do** to either <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. With 11.10 it wasn't possible to use <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, on a fresh install of 12.04 <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> was working properly.

Today it stopped working, if I try to bind <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> then the <kbd>control</kbd>key shows up in the keyboard binding as Primary.

I am running Unity, which in the past blocked <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, it seemed to have stopped blocking it on 12.04. It shouldn't affect <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

---

**Configuring either binding produces the following error in the gnome-do output:**

libdo-WARNING **: Binding 'space' failed!

libdo-WARNING **: Binding 'space' failed!

I'm stuck binding to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a combination of two problems:

The <kbd>super</kbd> problem is that Unity recently changed to grab the <kbd>super</kbd> key entirely - until version 5.6.0 it wolud pass on <kbd>super</kbd> keypresses that it didn't use to other applications that had registered bindings, like Do.

The second problem is due to a change in GTK - it's [bug #903566](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/903566) in Do, which is fixed in 0.9 and in Precise.  You can temporarily get a fixed Do from the [daily builds PPA](https://launchpad.net/~do-testers/+archive/ppa).

Comment: I'd like to try the recommendation about manually editing the shortcut in the from the bug ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/903566/comments/2 ) but I can't figure out where the configuration is stored. I thought it was in gconf-editor under /apps/gnome-do/preferences/Do/CorePreferences/SummonKeyBinding but this doesn't appear to update to reflect the current setting in the App and editing it doesn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately the daily builds PPA doesn't have builds for precise, the most recent release is oneiric.

Comment: Hah!  Thanks for reminding me - I should turn on Precise builds!

Comment: And done: the daily builds PPA now also builds for Precise.

Comment: It's working perfectly now, thank you very much RAOF.

Comment: I added the ppa from https://launchpad.net/~do-testers/+archive/ppa. Unfortunately my Precise will not update gnome-do to v0.9 . Also when I look at the above link I can only see 0.8.5+bzr1381-0~precise1. When doing apt uninstall and install of gnome-do I can see the package is fetched from ubuntu archive and not from the ppa. Any Ideas?

Comment: 0.8.5+bzr1381 *is* 0.9 (or, strictly speaking, post-0.9) I just haven't updated the version number for the packaging yet. If you've added the PPA but apt is pulling from the main archive then you must have a version newer than Do 0.8.5 in your main sources.  This could happen if you had precise-backports enabled, as I've pushed Do 0.9 there.

Answer (score 3):

According to [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/install-and-configure-gnome-do-in-ubuntu-unity/2535):

> Under standard GNOME, the key combination to call forth GNOME Do is
>   Super-Space, but the Super key is reserved for two very important
>   functions in Unity. If Super is tapped once, it will call up the
>   search dialog, and if it is pressed and held, the launcher icons will
>   display numbers (see Figure A). The user can then press the number
>   associated with the launcher to launch the application.
>
> So, after you launch GNOME Do, instead of using it to search for an
>   application or file, the very first thing that must be done is to
>   re-configure it to use a different hot key combination so that it
>   doesn’t use the Super key.

Are you using Unity? This may be the fundamental cause. Super **shouldn't** work with it.

Comment: I am using Unity, I can confirm that it did stop Super+Space in the past (11.10). It was no longer blocking it on 12.04. Regardless, it should not affect ctrl+alt+space.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> works in Gnome 3 (on Ubu 12.04).  The key binding for Super-Space does not.  Perhaps that's due to a more stingy binding of Super in G3 as well?