# Disable <super>-s (i.e. <mod4>-s) keyboard shortcut in 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04, shortcut-keys

Ever since upgrading to 12.04, I've lost my custom super-s shortcut that I've been using through xbindkeys.  Moreover, assigning super-s to commands using the "keyboard shortcuts" settings panel fails to take effect.  I am assuming some part of 12.04 UI is stealing that binding; I am running Xmonad using Gnome's fallback mode, so I have no idea what (if anything) super-s is supposed to do on 12.04.

What is stealing the super-s binding and how can I stop it?

Comment: Same problem for me. Not working <Super> with c/z/b for pause-play/previous trac/next trac. Nobody knows why :( It worked in 11.10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't bind gnome-do to Super + Space or Ctrl+Alt+Space](http://askubuntu.com/questions/113207/cant-bind-gnome-do-to-super-space-or-ctrlaltspace)

Comment: @aking1012: Linked question suggests that "Unity recently changed to grab the super key entirely" but doesn't offer a way of disabling this insane behavior.

Comment: Yes, the impression I got from your question was that you wanted to restore your bindings involving 'super'. You can't set bindings to 'super' anything. They all belong to unity.  If you're looking for the `How would I do it if I want to break things` you're talking about editing and recompiling Unity(don't).  If you think it's a bad behaviour file a bug: https://launchpad.net/unity

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Unity 3D, you can go to

```
gff --no-gui -setparam="CCSM/Expo/Keyboard\ Shortcut/*" setflag("disabled")
```

OR in human terms/you don't know what gff is: Open up CompizConfig-Settings-Manager, then go to "Expo", then inside the first tab "Keybinds" there should be a keybind called "Activate", click on the pencil next to it, and write "disabled"